# Prevent clicked button to cover the foreground view

Tags: android, button, layout

My goal is to create a button with an image on the top right-hand corner of it.

Something like this

[image]

The problem I run into when I click on the button the *help* icon is covered, it looks awkward, I would like to have it be always on top whereas the clicked button still have animation clicking effect but all this happens underneath of the *help* icon, instead, I have the following

[image]

My xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        style="@style/Material.BigButton"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="button"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>

    <Button
        style="@style/Material.BigButton"
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="help"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Spending a day looking for a similar problem, the only this I found it to disable a button animation `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` which doesn't match my design. I played with various of attributes like.

```
android:elevation=
android:translationZ=
```

Nothing worked for me.

Any direction will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 
[Adding Badge (Item Count) to Android Button](https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/adding-badge-item-count-to-android-button.html)